# ggplot equivalent of wireframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I would like to display a data set that is based on a grid. Currently, I am using the wireframe function to that end:

```
library(lattice)
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
xy <- expand.grid(x,y)

a <- xy[,1] * 0.2  + xy[,2]^2 * -0.85
b <- xy[,2] * 0.2  + xy[,1]^2 * -0.5
abxy <- cbind(a,b,xy)
wireframe(a + b~ Var1 * Var2, data = abxy)
```

I am using ggplot for other plots in the same manuscript and the wireframe plots don't fit to them aesthetically. Thus I was wondering whether a similar plot can be made with ggplot2.

Thanks, 
Jonathan

Comment: Please post sample data&code.

Comment: this question is too broad like this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I hope this is better.

Comment: I don't think ggplot can create a wireframe, but you could try a contour plot: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html.